# Decoding System.Security.SecureString

Tags: powershell

I want to decrypt a `System.Security.SecureString` to a readable password.

```
$mycrdentials = Get-Credential
$abc = $mycrdentials.Password
$Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($abc)
$result = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)
$result
```

But when I print result all I am getting is a blank space. What am I doing wrong? How can I get a readable password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted works for me. There is a simpler way, though:

```
PS C:\> $cred = Get-Credential   # entered "somepassword" as the password here

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
PS C:\> $cred.Password
System.Security.SecureString
PS C:\> $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
somepassword
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same for a remote desktop. This works for me. Is there a way by which i can retrieve password of a remote desktop ?

Comment: No. A remote desktop session is not an object storing a password. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is no way by which i can retrieve password of a remote desktop. Remote desktop is on the same domain as my desktop is ?

Comment: I would be rather surprised if this were possible.